# get input value from props

Tags: reactjs, forms

In react they say you can't change props directly (or at least you shouldn't).
But I wonder what should I do if I have an input in component and I have a value that comes as props?

I just wanted to know whether it's okay and what is the better way of doing this?

```
// product.amount comes from props
<input type="number" value={product.amount} onChange={(e) => onChangeProductAmount(e)}/>
```

so it seems like I want to change product.amount when input changes, but it is in props, so I shouldn't do it.
What should I do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the props are from the redux, you can change them in redux way only: calling an action creator that will fire an action.

There are packages that do that. I am not familiar with redux-form, but as far as I remember, it is one package that is maintaining the form state in redux. You can implement a similar thing yourself.

I do things differently: I use local state for controlling the input. When the user clicks 'submit', and if the values are valid, I call the action creator which fires the action that changes whatever needs to be changed in the redux store. However, these changes are not reflected directly in the form, as you want to do.

Some time ago I implemented a small app that handles forms this way. You may find it helpful: https://github.com/rahamin1/reactstrap-form

Comment: Yrs they are from parent component. But no, parent component receives these values from redux as props too. Parent component has no state too

Comment: Got it. I just thought that it would be strange to use redux form just for one input I have(

Comment: I didn't like redux form. I prefer to use local state, as I have done in my package. But both approaches are valid, I guess... A matter of taste.